# ggplot2: Legend with barplot and line

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

I am trying to produce a graph that shows averages by decile of two variables (as they have very different values, I added a second y-axis). On variable is represented with bars, the other one with a line. I struggle to make the a single legend to indicate the meaning of the bars and the line. (On the picture, I would like to get rid of the red square in the legend, and add a border to the blue square).

Here is a reproductible example:

'''

```
df <- data.frame(value1 = runif(100, 0, 1), 
                 value2 = runif(100, 0, 100),
                 weight = runif(100, 1, 5),
                 group = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 20))

df$value2 <- df$value2/100
ggplot(df) + 
  aes(weight = weight) + 
  stat_weighted_mean(aes(x = group, y = value1, color = "Value 1"), geom = "bar", fill = "#92C5DE") +
  stat_weighted_mean(aes(x = group, y = value2, group = 1, color = "Value 2"), geom = "line") +
  stat_weighted_mean(aes(x = group, y = value2), geom = "point", color = "#D6604D") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x/100, name = "Value 2")) + 
  labs(x = "group",y = "Value 1") + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Legend", breaks=c("Value 1","Value 2"), values=c("Value 1"="#143a67", "Value 2"="#D6604D"), 
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#92C5DE",NA), linetype = c("blank", "solid"))))
```

'''

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance for helping !

Comment: Try to just include Value 1 in the breaks statement as follows: scale_color_manual(name="Legend", breaks=c("Value 1"), values=c("Value 1"="#143a67"), 
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#92C5DE", NA), linetype = c("blank", "solid")))) +

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to first add a `linetype` scale and legend. Doing so allows to keep the outline in the legend for the `geom_bar` while removing the `line` glyph. Removing the outline for the `geom_line` is more tricky. Haven't found a way to do so via `override.aes`. So I switched to a custom `draw_key` function which builds on the default used for `geom_bar` but sets the `colour` to `NA` in case the `fill` is `NA` too.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

set.seed(123)

# Copy & paste from GeomBar$draw_key
draw_key_rect2 <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (is.null(data$linewidth)) {
    data$linewidth <- 0.5
  }
  lwd <- min(data$linewidth, min(size) / 4)

  # Set (outline) color to NA if no fill
  if (is.na(data$fill)) data$colour <- NA

  grid::rectGrob(width = unit(1, "npc") - unit(lwd, "mm"), height = unit(
    1,
    "npc"
  ) - unit(lwd, "mm"), gp = grid::gpar(
    col = data$colour %||% NA,
    fill = alpha(data$fill %||% "grey20", data$alpha),
    lty = data$linetype %||% 1, lwd = lwd * .pt, linejoin = params$linejoin %||%
      "mitre", lineend = params$lineend %||% "butt"
  ))
}

ggplot(df) +
  aes(weight = weight) +
  stat_weighted_mean(aes(x = group, y = value1, color = "Value 1"), geom = "bar", fill = "#92C5DE", key_glyph = "rect2") +
  stat_weighted_mean(aes(x = group, y = value2, group = 1, color = "Value 2", linetype = "Value 2"),
    geom = "line", key_glyph = "path"
  ) +
  stat_weighted_mean(aes(x = group, y = value2), geom = "point", color = "#D6604D") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x / 100, name = "Value 2")) +
  labs(x = "group", y = "Value 1") +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    name = "Legend",
    breaks = c("Value 1", "Value 2"),
    limits = c("Value 1", "Value 2"),
    values = c("Value 1" = "blank", "Value 2" = "solid"),
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Legend", breaks = c("Value 1", "Value 2"),
    values = c("Value 1" = "#143a67", "Value 2" = "#D6604D"),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
      fill = c("#92C5DE", NA),
      color = c("#143a67", "#D6604D")
    ))
  )
```

[image]